# CMake: write executables to multiple subdirectories

Tags: cmake

I have a source and build tree that looks something like this:

```
+-build/
  +-bin/
+-modules/
  +-src/
  +-tests/
    +-test1/
    +-test2/
```

I have also configured CMake to write the executables into the `build/bin`directory. That all works fine.

What I would like is to have *most* of my executables written into the `build/bin` directory, while those built from sources under the test directories be written into a `build/bin/tests` directory.

Is this possible? Can someone point me in the right direction?

I've tried setting the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable directly and I've tried using `set_target_properties`, but without success.

Ideally, I like to be able to set something in the CMakeLists.txt file in the `tests` directory and have it trickle down into the subdirectories.

Comment: "I have also configured CMake to write the executables into the `build/bin` directory." - How have you done that? Normally, similar way should be suited for place tests into `build/bin/tests` directory. And both variable `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and property `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` should work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I got my executables to be placed in `build/bin` by invoking `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)` at the root-level CMakeList.txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable as **many times** as you want. Each setting will affect only on the executables created since that setting until the next one.

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
# Futher executables will be placed under 'bin/'
add_executable(my_program <sources>...)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/tests)
# Futher executables will be placed under 'bin/tests/' instead
add_executable(test1 <sources>...)
add_executable(test2 <sources>...)
```

If you are creating the tests in the *separate* `CMakeLists.txt`, the settings can be made modular:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
# Futher executables will be placed under 'bin/'
add_executable(my_program <sources>...)

add_subdirectory(tests)
```

**tests/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/tests)
# Executables created below will be placed under 'bin/tests/' instead
add_executable(test1 <sources>...)
add_executable(test2 <sources>...)
```

---

Actually, when you call `add_executable`, it just uses the *current* value of the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable. This fact can be found in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) about `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` target property, which is affected by the variable.

Comment: Well, I thought I had tried this, but clearly I mucked something up. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.